# Unassigned reference exception when proceeding from scene to scene

Tags: unity, c#, scene

So, I have built a script in unity in c# called parralax. It basically parallaxes two backgrounds and looks like this:-

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Parralax : MonoBehaviour {

    public float startPos;
    public GameObject cam;
    public float parallaxEffect;

    public float length;
    public GameObject player;
    public float playerStartPos;
    public float maxDisplacement;
    void Start () {
        maxDisplacement = 0f;
        playerStartPos = player.transform.position.x;
        startPos = transform.position.x;
        cam = GameObject.Find ("Main Camera");
        length = GetComponent <SpriteRenderer> ().bounds.size.x;
    }


    void Update () {

        float dist = cam.transform.position.x * parallaxEffect;
        transform.position = new Vector2 (startPos + dist, transform.position.y);

    }
}
```

If I put it in respective background and assign a value to it, it works fine and runs smoothly. But, if I play the game scene-wise i.e. 1st scene to 2nd scene to 3rd scene; it crashes and says:-

```
Unassigned reference exception:- You need to set variable cam in inspector
```

Even though, it runs on the same scene, it doesn't run after I play it scene- wise. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## When you change scenes, the camera gets destroyed

Because the camera gets destroyed (and the new scene has a new one) your `cam` variable no longer points to the main camera. You can detect this and do the appropriate thing,

```
void Update () {
    if(cam == null) cam = Camera.main
    float dist = cam.transform.position.x * parallaxEffect;
    transform.position = new Vector2 (startPos + dist, transform.position.y);
}
```

Comment: Good catch. As he said the 'cached' cam will be 'null' for a split second so even if the new scene assigns the new one. The error will still register. Typically should always be checking a null in that case for good practice.

Comment: Aborting-if-still-null would be a good idea here too, sure, though was't the main issue being addressed, which was that once it went null, it would stay null forever. (And not actually-null-because-Unity-wrapper-objects, but may as well be null).

Answer (score 1):

Like it says. "You need to set variable cam in inspector".

To do this:

1. In Hierarchy panel right and click choose "Create Empty" to add a new Game Object and rename it as ParralaxController (you can give any name you want).
2. In Inspector panel press `Add Component` and type Parralax then choose the Parralax script below.
3. When this ParralaxController is selected drag your "Main Camera" and drop it to the area of `Cam` in Inspector Panel.

Alternatively define your camera object like this:

```
public Camera cam;
```

and in Start Method write this.

```
cam = Camera.main;
```

Comment: `cam = Camera.main` is (effectively) the same as `GameObject.Find ("Main Camera");`. `Camera.main` is just a property-method that calls `GameObject.FindWithTag`, so changing scenes is going to leave `cam` just as undefined when the main camera gets destroyed.